# How do I indent option 6 of \cventry?

Tags: spacing, lists, moderncv

I would like to use bullet points in my CV, but I do not like the look of it directly under the title text.  I have:

```
\cventry{start-end}{More description about job title}
{Project I work on}{}{}{\begin{itemize}\item First bullet 
point about what I do \item Second item about what I do \end{itemize}}
```

If I don't itemize the list and just add `\hspace{5mm}` and `\newline\hspace*{5mm}` it's fine, but I like the look of bullet points.  Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functionality of [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to adjust the `leftmargin`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\firstname{Some}
\familyname{Dude}
\title{CV}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Using cventry:}
\cventry
  {start-end}
  {More description about job title}
  {Project I work on}
  {}
  {}
  {\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2em,nosep]
    \item First bullet point about what I do
    \item Second item about what I do
  \end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

The listing structure in [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) tends to be quite dense (or tight), hence the addition of `nosep` to remove the insertion of any vertical spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple command

```
\hspace*{.5em}
```

e.g.

```
\cventry{year--year}{degree or job title}{institution or employer}{city}{grade}
{\hspace*{.5em} description}
```